# Using conditionals in Jquery to place a Fancybox display at a lower spot on the page

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where it is necessary for a Fancybox to display below a video at the top of the page.

```
$(function() {
    $('.index').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 'slow'); 
    });
    $(".index").fancybox({
        'title'    : 'INDEX',       
        'width'    : 615,
        'height'   : 450,
                 ...
        'type'     : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

This works well. The page drops down 500 pixels - below the video - and the FB is invoked.

But what I require is for the scrolling down to occur only if the wepage is right at the top.

So, something like:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.index').click(function(){
            if 500 pixels or more from the top {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 'slow');
            }); 
    });
    $(".index").fancybox({
            etc.
```

How might I go about writing that conditional line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on the `window` object to determine the current vertical scroll position of the page.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 500) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I should have written 500 pixels or LESS from the top invokes the scroll down, so changing your answer from greater than to less than works! Thanks.